# How to delist a function from a methods namespace such as `S3`?

Tags: r, plot, methods, namespaces

The `plot` functions in R are tied to an `S3method`.  By default,

```
> methods("plot")
 [1] plot.acf*           plot.data.frame*    plot.decomposed.ts* plot.default       
 [5] plot.dendrogram*    plot.density*       plot.ecdf           plot.factor*       
 [9] plot.formula*       plot.function       plot.hclust*        plot.histogram*    
[13] plot.HoltWinters*   plot.isoreg*        plot.lm*            plot.medpolish*    
[17] plot.mlm*           plot.ppr*           plot.prcomp*        plot.princomp*     
[21] plot.profile.nls*   plot.raster*        plot.spec*          plot.stepfun       
[25] plot.stl*           plot.table*         plot.ts             plot.tskernel*     
[29] plot.TukeyHSD*
```

I can manually define a new function at the console:

```
plot.tukey = function(x) {}
```

It automatically gets listed in the methods("plot") based on its naming convention:

```
> methods("plot")
 [1] plot.acf*           plot.data.frame*    plot.decomposed.ts* plot.default       
 [5] plot.dendrogram*    plot.density*       plot.ecdf           plot.factor*       
 [9] plot.formula*       plot.function       plot.hclust*        plot.histogram*    
[13] plot.HoltWinters*   plot.isoreg*        plot.lm*            plot.medpolish*    
[17] plot.mlm*           plot.ppr*           plot.prcomp*        plot.princomp*     
[21] plot.profile.nls*   plot.raster*        plot.spec*          plot.stepfun       
[25] plot.stl*           plot.table*         plot.ts             plot.tskernel*     
[29] plot.tukey          plot.TukeyHSD*     
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

### How do I `delist` or `unregister` the function from the default `S3` namespace?

That is, I want plot.tukey to be declared a function, but not be attached to the `S3` namespace.  Is there an `unUseMethod` functionality?

Comment: The `methods` function ultimately calls `.S3methods` which basically just searches for functions whose name start with "plot.". Unless you get in the special `tools::nonS3methods()` list, basically it's just a text match. If you don't want to be in that list, don't use `.` in your function name. The S3 dispatch is very primitive and simple and relies on convention rather than configuration to work (for the most part). That's why most R style guides recommend not using "." in variable or functions names. They are mostly "grandfathered" in.

Comment: There is no S3 namespace, namespaces are for packages. I don't believe what you are asking is possible, `plot` is a generic and once you write a method for it, the S3 methods mechanism will find it, it will be on the search path.

Comment: @MrFlick So you are saying `.S3method("plot", "function", plot.tukey)` is the "registration" method that happens behind the scenes.  What is the "unregistration" method?

Comment: `registerS3method` is an internal function.  where is its INVERSE?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I was pointing to the `.S3methods` function, not the `.S3method` function. The idea of "registered" S3 methods came later in R's lifetime. Like around 3.5 or so I think. But that was mostly for R packages. There is no registration required if you define a function in your global namespace. Basically to keep all older R code working, S3 dispatch happens by literally doing a string match on a function's name.

Comment: Either define the function in another environment (`e <- local(plot.tukey = function(x) {})`), define it in a package and don't register it as an S3 method, or use a different name for the function.

Comment: "Is there an `unUseMethod` functionality?" No.

Comment: There is `unUse` under the hood, if I keep digging.  `.S3methods` does the registration, I just have to figure out how and REVERSE it... I see ```S3reg <- unlist(lapply(loadedNamespaces(), function(i) ls(get(".__S3MethodsTable__.", 
            envir = asNamespace(i)), pattern = name)))
``` which maybe is where R is storing the registrations.  When I `copy/paste` the function into the console, is it calling `.S3methods`?

Comment: Note that code that works for package is different than code that works for functions in your global environment. Your question is currently about creating a function in the global environment. There is no explicit registration required in that case. Currently only packages are required to explicitly register S3 methods.

Comment: When I copy/paste a function `plot.tukey = function(x) {}` into the console, it builds `body` and `formals` and `srcref` *AND* it registers the function based on name (`plot.*`) to a `".__S3MethodsTable__."` ... where is that function that processes the copy/paste and builds these features (and calls S3)?

Comment: `ls( get(".__S3MethodsTable__.", envir = asNamespace("base") ) , pattern="plot")`

Comment: I can't replicate that behavior. If I run `plot.test <- function() {"test"}` and then run `plot.test" %in% ls( get(".__S3MethodsTable__.", envir = asNamespace("base") ) , pattern="plot")` I see "FALSE". That new function is not listed in the output. Tested with R 4.2.0

Comment: That is correct.  the namespace `base` doesn't contain `plot.tukey` but the GLOBAL ENV does.  `methods` calls `.S3methods` ... I also see `registerS3method` and `setNamespaceInfo`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are wrestling deep in the bowels of R and your motivation is a desire to define

```
plot.tukey = function(x) {}
```

which would show up on a `methods("plot")` call
rather than
say

```
plot_tukey = function(x) {}
```

which would not ?

Comment: `plot.tukey` is a legal function name.  I don't want to interfere with the default namespace, but I do want to use my name and not be hindered by `UseMethods` keys defined by `R-DEV`.  I am not a `snake_case_guy` as `plot.homageToTukey` is how I roll.  I want to play nice, but not be forced to change my naming convention.  Obviously "." would break in C++ but it has a nice sense of OBJ.ACTION or CLASS.METHOD

Comment: @mshaffer Work with the language not against it.

Comment: stackoverflow doesnt let me provide a block of code so I'll just point out that 
`awk^ward.funct!on/name=123` is a perfectly legal function name :P if it is defined with backticks

Comment: `plot.tukey` is not ridiculous like `awk^ward`.  Be serious!  I am not the first one that have run into conflicts with the default S3 Methods.  To be a friendly programmer, I want to remove it from the S3 namespace to avoid confusion.  I am not trying to register or hook into S3 method "plot" so how do I remove it.  I can play nice, my way.